# Not receiving a signal from a subclassed QVideoWidget

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I'm developing a video player application,
I have subclassed `QVideoWidget`, then I promoted `QWidget` in my ui file to this subclassed QVideoWidget.

Now I want to call a function defined in another class by a signal from the subclassed QVideoWidget.

So I defined a signal that I emit when the user presses the `videowidget`, and connected it to a slot in the other class (the function I want to call), but the slot never gets called.

`videowidget.h` :

```
#ifndef VIDEOWIDGET_H
#define VIDEOWIDGET_H

#include <QVideoWidget>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QObject>

class videowidget : public QVideoWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
     videowidget();
signals:
    void videoClicked();
protected:
    void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;
};
#endif // VIDEOWIDGET_H
```

`videowidget.cpp` :

```
#include "videowidget.h"
videowidget::videowidget()
{

}

void videowidget::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{

    setFullScreen(!isFullScreen());
    event->accept();
}

void videowidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        emit videoClicked();
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

`widget.h` :

```
private slots:
     void videoClicked();
private:
   videowidget *videoPlayer;
```

`widget.cpp` :

```
Widget::Widget()
{
    videoPlayer = new videowidget();

    /*Widget*/
    Bottom = ui->Bottom; /*Bottom was declare in Player.h as a QWidget*/
    connect(videoPlayer, &videowidget::videoClicked, this, &Widget::videoClicked);
}

void Widget::videoClicked()
{
    Bottom->setVisible(false);
    qDebug()<<"pressed from slot";
}
```

If I print something in the function that emits the signal, it works, but the slot from the other class is never called.

I also have tried to directly print a string instead of calling the slot, but it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a minimal reproducible example with comments to explain what was wrong and how to fix it:

`widget.h`

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QVideoWidget>
#include "videowidget.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class Widget; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Widget();

private slots:
    void videoClicked();

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
    videowidget *videoPlayer;
    QWidget *Bottom;
};
#endif // WIDGET_H
```

widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "./ui_widget.h"
#include "videowidget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    
    //The problem's here

    //this new object is unnecessary and it's not being set visible 
    videoPlayer = new videowidget(this);
     
    ui->video_player->show();

    //I removed Bottom because it was an unnecessary intermediate
    //use ui->video_player directly as a sender, since it is the promoted widget
    //and the one being displayed and clicked
    connect(ui->video_player, &videowidget::videoClicked, this, &Widget::videoClicked);
    
    //videoPlayer was not the widget you were clicking, hence why you never got a response
    //connect(videoPlayer, &videowidget::videoClicked, this, &Widget::videoClicked);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Widget::videoClicked()
{
    qDebug()<<"pressed";
    ui->video_player->setVisible(false);
}
```

videowidget.h

```
#ifndef VIDEOWIDGET_H
#define VIDEOWIDGET_H

#include <QVideoWidget>
#include <QMouseEvent>

class videowidget : public QVideoWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    videowidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

signals:
    void videoClicked();

protected:
    void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;
};

#endif // VIDEOWIDGET_H
```

videowidget.cpp

```
#include "videowidget.h"

videowidget::videowidget(QWidget *parent)
{
}

void videowidget::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    setFullScreen(!isFullScreen());
    event->accept();
}

void videowidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        videoClicked();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say:

> I have made a class and Re-implemented QVideoWidget in it

I'm assuming you have derived from QVideoWidget and overloaded the `mousePressEvent`.

This is the widget you have displayed within a window.  When you click on this widget, you want to emit a signal (`videoClicked`) that is received by a slot (also called `videoClicked`) in another class called `Widget`.

The following code will do this:

Disclaimer, this is NOT production level code!

Firstly, here is my version of the derived class that implements `mousePressEvent`:

videowidget.h:

```cpp
#ifndef VIDEOWIDGET_H
#define VIDEOWIDGET_H

#include <QVideoWidget>

class videowidget : public QVideoWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    videowidget();
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);

signals:
    void videoClicked();

};

#endif // VIDEOWIDGET_H
```

videoWidget.cpp:

```cpp
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include "videowidget.h"


videowidget::videowidget()
{
    qDebug()<<"videowidget created";

}

void videowidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        qDebug()<<"videowidget pressed";
        emit videoClicked();
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

widget.h:

```cpp
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

private:
    QWidget *Bottom;
signals:

public slots:
    void videoClicked();

};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

widget.cpp:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include "widget.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

widget::widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget{parent}
{
    Bottom = new QWidget(this);

}

void widget::videoClicked()
{
    Bottom->setVisible(false);
    /*Bottom is a QWidget*/
    qDebug()<<"widget pressed";
}
```

MainWindow.h:

```cpp
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class videowidget;
class widget;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    videowidget *videoWidget;
    widget *Widget;

};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp:

```cpp
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include "videowidget.h"
#include "widget.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    , videoWidget(new videowidget)
    , Widget(new widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    auto layout = new QHBoxLayout(ui->centralwidget);

    layout->addWidget(videoWidget);

    connect(videoWidget, &videowidget::videoClicked, Widget, &widget::videoClicked);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete Widget;
    delete videoWidget;
    delete ui;
}
```

Main.cpp:

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

.pro file:

```qmake
QT       += core gui
QT += multimediawidgets
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp \
    videowidget.cpp \
    widget.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h \
    videowidget.h \
    widget.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

This builds and runs on Qt 5.12.12, Ubuntu 20.04 with the following output in the Debug Window:

> videowidget created
> videowidget pressed
> widget pressed
> videowidget pressed
> widget pressed
> videowidget pressed
> widget pressed
> videowidget pressed
> widget pressed
> videowidget pressed
> widget pressed

Comment: You are making a new Videowidget, I'm not, I have QWidget in the ui file already, and promoted it to the videowidget class, also I have Edited some-things in the code, it doesn't work, the signal never goes to the another Class